# Windows 8 WinRT Xaml Grid inside InlineUIContainer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

In my Windows 8 ItemDetail view, I want to add an overlay image to the standard image which is contained inside an InlineUIContainer element.

This is the xaml I am using:

```
<Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">
    <InlineUIContainer>
        <Grid x:Name="MediaGrid" Width="560" Height="315" Margin="0,20,0,10">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </Grid.Background>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Image x:Name="OverlayImage" Visibility="{Binding ShowVideo, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/play-icon.png"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </InlineUIContainer>
</Paragraph>
```

This works perfectly when the app is in landscape mode. However as soon as I rotate, or open the app in portrait mode I receive the error:

`WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetName image. Additional information: Unspecified error` in LayoutAwarePage.cs `VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, DetermineVisualState(ApplicationView.Value), false);`

Does anyone have any idea why? After a little process of elimination, it seems to happen when I have a Grid inside the InlineUIContainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a control name 'image' is missing and is only triggered when the VisualState is changed